# PowerShell: what is System.IO.StreamWriter and System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo?

Tags: powershell, reference, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

I'm learning PowerShell. With [System.IO.StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netcore-3.1) and [System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netcore-3.1), is it more accurate to call them "Classes"? Or can they be referred to as "new-objects" as well?

```bsh
$foo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.IO.StreamWriter` and `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` are *classes*, and more broadly *types* (or *data types*) in .NET

PowerShell runs on .NET, and in .NET's type system a "class" is a *blueprint* for the behavior of what we call *reference-type objects*.

```
$foo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
```

In the statement above, we ask `New-Object` to create *an **instance*** of `ProcessStartInfo` - that is, we want an object that *behaves* as prescribed by the `ProcessStartInfo` class. We might also say that the resulting object (now referenced by `$foo`), is *of type ProcessStartInfo*.

### Reference types vs value types

Above I referred to *reference type objects*. The reason this is important is that .NET types can be grouped into to *kinds* of types - *reference types* and *value types*.

Value types are things like built-in numerical types (`[int]`, `[double]`, `[decimal]`, `[bool]` etc.) - but also more complex data types like `[datetime]`, the type of object returned by `Get-Date`.

The reason this distinction (reference vs value) matter is that they act differently when assigned and stored. With value types, any assignment will cause .NET to *copy the value* of the object to the assignment target:

```
$a = 1    
$b = $a   # Assign value of $a to $b
$a++      # Modify value of $a
$b        # Is $b 1 or 2?
```

During the assignment operation `$b = $a`, PowerShell looks at `$a`, sees that its value, `1`, is of type `[int]` and stores *a new copy of the value 1* in `$b` - so even though we increment the value of `$a` to 2, the value of `$b` is unchanged.

With reference types, this is not the case. Reference types objects are stored and passed around *by reference*:

```
$a = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo]::new("calc.exe")
$b = $a
$a.FileName = "notreally.exe"
$b.FileName             # Is $b.FileName "calc.exe" or "notreally.exe"?
```

In this case, because `[System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo]` is a reference type, `$a` doesn't contain the *value* (ie. the data associated with the object), it only contains a *reference* or a *pointer* to where the data is really stored in memory, and assigning `$b = $a` doesn't copy the object, instead both `$a` and `$b` ends up referencing the same underlying object, and modification of one is reflected when interrogated through the other.